# How to hide jQuery Mobile Anchor Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to hide / show certain anchor buttons depending on conditions, but currently this is not working.

I have several jQuery Mobile anchor buttons that look something like this:

```
<a id="lteAlabamaButton" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true"   onclick="lteGaugeRefresh('Alabama')">Alabama</a>

<a id="lteArkansasButton" href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" onclick="lteGaugeRefresh('Arkansas')">Arkansas</a>
```

.
.
.

I tried `$(buttonId).hide()` but it does not work. 
I also tried using`.css('display','none')` but that doesn't work either.

These anchor buttons are sitting in the content area of a jQuery mobile popup.

Comment: Could you place them into container `<div>`s and hide those?

Comment: show us your implementation of your method `lteGaugeRefresh`

Comment: Is your selector like this? `$('#buttonId').`

Comment: Yes, my selector is fine. I also tried to wrap it in a div and hide that but no luck.

Comment: The onClick function is not responsible for the hide/show calls. When the page is loaded, based on parameters from an http request, I loop through a set of buttons and (optimally) I want to hide some based on certain criteria. I could disable the anchors, but I am also trying to minimize visual clutter (there are 35 of them total...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a id="lteAlabamaButton" href="" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Alabama</a>
<a id="lteArkansasButton" href="" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Arkansas</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('[data-role="button"]').click(function() {
       var title = $(this).find('.ui-btn-text').html();
       $(this).hide();            
  });

})
```